# Is :: used for anything other than "global::"

Tags: c#, namespaces

Title pretty much explains it all. Are there any other values for the "[namespace alias qualifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx)" (what?)

Can programmers define new ones?

It seems strange to list :: as an operator in itself, and the page seems to hint that there could be other values: "The namespace alias qualifier **can** be global."

Answer (score 2):

See the page for [`extern alias`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx) for a example where they use `GridV1::Grid` and `GridV2::Grid`.

The main place you would use it is when you have two DLLs you are including in your project and both DLLs have a class with the same name in the same namespace (for example you are using two versions of the same DLL in your project). The `::` operator lets you specify which DLL you are referring to when there is a naming conflict like that.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. It's odd that the page for the operator doesn't mention this.

Comment: "both DLLs have a class with the same name in the same namespace (for example you are using two versions of the same DLL in your project)" - Doesn't it bad design? Or you are referring to using different versions of component at same time?

Comment: @Amit: Presumably the conflicting names are chosen by two or more third-party library vendors, so there is no over-arching design.

Comment: @Amit Me personally, I ran in to it when we had to use two versions of the same component due to some features we relied on did not work on newer versions of the componet. But Ben's situation is one I have seen before as well where multiple 3rd parties all insert in to the same namespace at the same time (mainly see it in Mod development for games, everyone inserting in to the game's namespace instead of their own).

Comment: Thanks scott and @Ben i totally agree with your comment. My intension of raising this was, we should not fall regularly to this scenario and unavoidable instaces should be minimal so that it should not pollute code.